# Batch File pass argument, possibly null

Tags: batch-file, parameter-passing

Any help here would be appreciated. I am trying to optionally pass in an argument (a string) to a batch file. If the argument ("log") is passed in, it will continue with the script and redirect output to a log file; if the argument is not passed in, the script will continue without redirecting the output to a log file.

Thanks,
Mike

```
REM File1

REM where [log] is an optional argument
CALL File2.cmd [log]
```

```
REM File2

REM if the first argument is "log", then activate logging and continue
IF [%1]=="log" ECHO Logging is enabled.

REM if the "log" argument is not provided, then continue with logging disabled
IF [%1]==[] ECHO Logging not enabled.
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's your code and what's pseudocode. Is `IF [%1]=="log" <logging enabled, continue..>` the real, actual, complete line in your script? Because if so, I see three different things that are wrong on that line.

Comment: Why would you think `[log]` equals `"log"`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're complicating things unnecessarily, in `File1` use `CALL File2.cmd > [log]` to output to a log file, use `CALL File2.cmd > NUL` to output to nothing, and use `CALL File2.cmd > CON` to output to the console. _(Remembering that you can also include StdErr too)_. This way, no changes are necessary in the second file, and the only thing you're doing differently is adding the `>` character at `Call` time!

Comment: Will update this later today. Basically, I was using the notation of [optional] and <required>, such as that seen in Powershell documentation. @Squashman that is not what I thought, I appreciate your criticism, though. @ Compo I may end up using something similar, thank you for the idea!

Comment: @SomethingDark I updated this line to what my testing code looks like